# Image with different anchor targets

Tags: javascript, html, image, target, banner

How can I get the "_self" target to be change-able depending on the url selected? So for example

website1: _self
website2: _blank

Is this even possible?

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Advertise Spot #1</title>

   <script>
        var links = ["http://www.website1.com","http://www.website2.com"];
        var images = ["https://www.website1.com/Content/Banners/2019_8_21_11_41_193.png","https://www.website2.com/Content/Banners/2019_8_21_11_35_493.png"];
         var i = 0;
        var renew = setInterval(function(){
            if(links.length == i){
                i = 0;
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById("bannerImage").src = images[i]; 
            document.getElementById("bannerLink").href = links[i];
        i++;

        }
        },3000);
        </script>

<a id="bannerLink" href="http://www.website1.com" onclick="void window.open(this.href,"_self"); return false;">
<img id="bannerImage" src="https://www.website1.com/Content/Banners/2019_8_21_11_41_193.png" width="900" height="900" alt="Website Ads">
</a>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not change the "target" attribute with the anchor's href-attribute?

HTML:

```
<a id="bannerLink" href="http://www.website1.com">
  <img id="bannerImage" src="https://picsum.photos/50" >
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
var links = [{
 href: "https://www.website1.com",
 img: "https://picsum.photos/id/237/100/100",
 self: true
},{
 href: "https://www.website2.com",
 img: "https://picsum.photos/id/235/100/100",
 self: true
}];

var i = 0;
var renew = setInterval(function(){
  if (links.length === i) {
    i = 0;
  }  else {
    document.getElementById("bannerLink").href = links[i].href; 
    document.getElementById("bannerLink").target = (links[i].self) ? "_self" : "_blank";;
    document.getElementById("bannerImage").src = links[i].img; 
    i++;
  }
},3000);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jaonLcpw/

Comment: Thank you so much, this seems to fix the main issue I was having. The problem though I probably should have explained better is that, other then the target problem, I also couldn't figure out how to scale this to like 3 or 4 or more links/websites and different targets.

Comment: Just put your information in an array of objects as shown in https://jsfiddle.net/jaonLcpw/